# Display Quantity in full form

Tags: output-formatting, units

Is there a way to display `Quantity[]` in full form in the output? 
I know you could use `Quantity[valuse, Unit]//InputForm`, but what I want is something like `Quantity[Placeholder["tip"], "Meters"]`, but with an actual named placeholder instead of the code.

(I am trying to use this in the user interface, so the the placeholder could also serve as a tooltip box. This is something I would hope it could looklike: 
[image])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Defer[Quantity][Placeholder["tip"],"Meters"]
```

[image]

or

```
HoldForm[Quantity][Placeholder["tip"],"Meters"]
```

[image]

The second method requires `ReleaseHold` to evaluate.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `Inactive` in **V10**, of course the appearance will be slightly different.

```
Inactive[Quantity][Placeholder["Tooltip"], "Meters"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And use `Activate` to evaluate it: